# Page Object Pattern - problem with Webdriverwait - python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm learning a python and selenium. I try to create a new project with Page object pattern and I have a problem with WebdriverWait, you can see you my code, and next, I write how error I get.

The method in a page:

```
def testStart(self):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 
        StartPage.username))
    )
    user = self.driver.find_element(*StartPage.username)
    user.click()
```

My test - simply ;)

```
startPage = StartPage(self.driver)
    startPage.testStart()
```

And locators:

```
username = (By.ID, 'username')
```

And Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
```

When I check method in a page on:

```
def testStart(self):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 
        *StartPage.username))
    )
    user = self.driver.find_element(*StartPage.username)
    user.click()
```

I had:

```
TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

How I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error 1:**

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
>   invalid argument: 'value' must be a string

Your `StartPage.username` is: `username = (By.ID, 'username')`.

Now when you wait for this element with:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 
    *StartPage.username))
)
```

You are passing it a `By` object, not an `ID`...

This you can fix with:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(*StartPage.username)
)
```

Or change `StartPage.username` to: `username = 'username'` and keep the code in the wait...

For more info see [page-objects](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html).

Hope this helps you!